# What does casting an IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerator<T> do

Tags: c#, .net, linq, resharper, ienumerable

I'm in the process of training a beginner some core concepts of C#. While creating an IEnumerable for random numbers a mistake in his code suggested casting an `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerator<T>`

I know that neither of those interfaces implement each other so what struck me was that neither ReSharper nor the compiler nor the runtime threw an exception.

Here is some example code:

```cs
public class SomeEnumerable : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<int> _numbers;

    public SomeEnumerable()
    {
        _numbers = Enumerable.Range(0,10);
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator<int>) _numbers;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Unexpectedly the `GetEnumerator`-Method compiles perfectly fine. When the beginner mistakenly put in the private field "_numbers" ReSharper even suggested to add the explicit cast I've included.

Now consider the following test code:

```
var someEnumerable = new SomeEnumerable();
Console.WriteLine($"Number of elements: {someEnumerable.Count()}");
```

The `Count()`-Method invokes the enumerator and the output is this:

> Number of elements: 0

Strangely if you change the constructor of the class so that it uses an `IList<T>` for the private field

```
public SomeEnumerable()
{
    _numbers = Enumerable.Range(0,10).ToArray();
}
```

the code throws a proper InvalidCastException.

I know that `Enumerable.Range()` uses the `yield` statement in its implementation as well as that the compiler can do some magic as soon as the `GetEnumerator` method is implemented, so maybe that's a hint.

Thus my questions are:

1. Why is the cast legal and why isn't there a warning? (Compile time/Resharper)
2. Why can you cast an `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerator` but not an `IList` to an `IEnumerator` without getting a warning (ReSharper)
3. Why does invoking GetEnumerator by Count/foreach/etc. yield an empty result?
4. If there is a good reason for this to work, which part of the framework makes use of that?

Some Clarification:
I know that it shouldn't be done this way, and I know it can never work this way. But I am interested in why the code results in IL that is compiled and executed perfectly fine but yields such strange results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the cast legal and why isn't there a warning?

The whole *point* of a cast is that you're telling the compiler, "I know that you don't think that this type is actually this other type, but I know more than you, let me treat it as if it's this other type and throw an exception at runtime if I'm wrong.

> Why can you cast an IEnumerable to an IEnumerator but not an IList to an IEnumerator without getting a warning (ReSharper)

You *can't* cast any `IEnumerable<T>` to an `IEnumerator<T>`.  This particular object just happens to implement both interfaces.  Other objects, such as the `SomeEnumerable` you wrote, will just implement one or the other, and casts like this will fail (at runtime) for them.

> Why does invoking GetEnumerator by Count/foreach/etc. yield an empty result?

The object doesn't expect you to cast it to another type and start calling methods on it.  You're violating the contract of the type.  If you want it to function properly, call `GetEnumerator` and it will give you a proper enumerator.  As it is, you're getting an enumerator that hasn't been properly initialized, since you subverted the method that initializes its data.

> If there is a good reason for this to work, which part of the framework makes use of that?

It's simply a type that looks something like:

```
public class SomeClass: IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerator<int>
{ 
    //...
}
```

You can write a class like that, if you want.

Comment: This leaves some things unanswered. Which class doesn't expect me to cast it to another type and why would this class use both interfaces?

Comment: @JanWolf The class that you're casting to `IEnumerator<T>`.  If you want to know why the person that designed the class designed it the way they did you could ask them.  We can only guess at why they would have chosen to design the class the way that they did.

Comment: I'd be interested in specifics. I know how to do it properly, this is not the question, I know that it shouldn't work, this isn't the question as well. The question is why does it work (Why does this class implement the two interfaces), what does the resulting enumerator do (What is the Enumerator that is being returned) 
I know this isn't proper code

Comment: @JanWolf It works because the author of that type implemented both interfaces.  It's really that simple.  They didn't write the code such that you'd cast the object to the other interface, so it doesn't work in that situation (unless you're really careful in how you do it), they wrote it so that they could provide the object in places where either interface was expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137017/discussion-between-jan-wolf-and-servy).

Comment: @JanWolf See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs -- `abstract class Iterator<TSource> : IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerator<TSource>` -- the answer to your "why" question is ... engineering. Since an IEnumerable always needs an IEnumerator to go with it, someone chose to package them up into one class. (Yes, that violates principles, but people do that all the time for pragmatic reasons.)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the type that is returned by `Enumerable.Range(0,10)`:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<RangeIterator>d__110
```

This type, which generated by the compiler, is a little state machine that keeps track of iterations during `yield` statements. This `yield` statement is executed internally by the [`Enumerable.Range`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,fda9d378095a6464,references) statement.

Running ...

```
Enumerable.Range(0,10).GetType().GetInterfaces()
```

... returns

```
typeof(IEnumerable<Int32>) 
typeof(IEnumerable) 
typeof(IEnumerator<Int32>) 
typeof(IDisposable) 
typeof(IEnumerator)
```

So there you've got it: it implements both `IEnumerable<Int32>` and `IEnumerator<Int32>`. That's why the cast succeeds. Casting always casts the *acutal* type of an object, not its *compile-time* type. The compile-time type of `_number` is `IEnumerable<int>`, but it's actual type is still the generated type.

Knowing that, it's clear why creating an array causes an invalid cast exception: it doesn't implement `IEnumerator<int>`.

So why does `new SomeEnumerable()` return `0` elements? I have to speculate a bit here, but I think it's because the state machine has been used twice here, first as enumerator and then as enumerable. In the second usage its internal pointer is already at the last iteration.

Comment: Thank you. The hint about the state machine + looking at the decompiled code and applying what you've said seems to be very conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles without a problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class C {
    public void M() {
        IEnumerable<double> x = null;
        var y = (IEnumerator<double>)x;
    }
}
```

This code compiles without a problem, too

```
public class C {
    public void M() {
        IMagic1<double> x = null;
        var y = (IMagic2<int>)x;
    }
}

public interface IMagic1<T> {
   IMagic2<T> Magic();
}

public interface IMagic2<T> {
    void Magic2();
}
```

Both compile because of you telling the compiler that you know better by casting.

This produces a runtime error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace xyz
{

    public class C {
        public void M() {
            IMagic1<double> x = new X1();
            var y = (IMagic2<int>)x;
        }
    }

    public class X1 : IMagic1<double> {
        public IMagic2<double> Magic() {
            return new X2();
        }        
    }

    public class X2 : IMagic2<double> {
        public void Magic2() {

        }        
    }

    public interface IMagic1<T> {
       IMagic2<T> Magic();
    }

    public interface IMagic2<T> {
        void Magic2();
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new C().M();
        }
    }
}
```

This produces a runtime error:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = (IEnumerator<double>)(new double[] {0}).AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

This doesn't:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = (IEnumerator<int>)Enumerable.Range(10,1);
    }
}
```

So your problem seems about Enumerable.Range returning an object that implements IEnumerable and IEnumerator.

Comment: That's a lot of words to tell what I already concluded and Servy indicated by saying "This particular object just happens to implement both interfaces".